# Android app - ListView is not working

Tags: java, android, xml

App is not working I don't know reason.

***CustomView.java***

```
public class CustomView extends Activity {
         ListView list;
         String titles[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles);
         int images[] = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.movies);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    CustomList adapter = new CustomList(CustomView.this);
    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),titles[+position],Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}

public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    final Activity context;
    public CustomList(Activity context){
        super(context,R.layout.listitem,titles);
        this.context = context;

    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        double randomValue = Math.random();
        double randomYear = Math.random();
        LayoutInflater inflater =context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem,null,true);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        TextView title = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView rating = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
        TextView genre = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
        TextView year = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.year);

        title.setText(titles[pos]);
        imageView.setImageResource(images[pos]);
        rating.setText(((int)randomValue*9)+0+"."+pos) ;
        genre.setText("DRAMA");
        year.setText(((int)randomYear+1960)+1930);


        return rowView;
    }

  }
}
```

Layout files
***main.xml***

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

tools:context="com.example.kim.customlistview.CustomView">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/listview" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

listitem ***listitem.xml***

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="#eeeeee"
 android:padding="8dp"
 >

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
    android:textSize="17dp"

    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rating"
    android:layout_below="@+id/title"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
    android:textSize="15dip"
    />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/genre"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rating"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
    android:textSize="13dip"

    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/year"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textSize="12dip"
    />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

resources ***string.xml***

```
 <resources>
 <string name="app_name">CustomListView</string>
 <string-array name="titles">
    <item>"The Wizard of Oz (1939)"</item>
    <item>"Citizen kane (1950)"</item>
    <item>"A Hard Day's Night (1934)"</item>
    <item>"A Funny (1959)"</item>
    <item>"HELLO (1943)"</item>
 </string-array>
 </resources>
```

***array.xml***

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
     <array name="movies">
      <item>@drawable/movie1</item>
      <item>@drawable/movie2</item>
      <item>@drawable/movie3</item>
      <item>@drawable/movie4</item>
      <item>@drawable/movie5</item>
     </array>
  </resources>
```

Stack trace:

```
10-29 16:25:26.221 9745-9745/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.example.kim.customlistview, PID: 9745
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.kim.customlistview/com.example.kim.customlistview.CustomView}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference



Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
                                                 at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:92)
```

Answer (score 0):

Intanziate `titles[]` and `images[]` insde `onCreate()` method, otherwise the context required to call `getResources()` is null.

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines into onCreate Method of Activity

> ```
>    String titles[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles);
>    int images[] = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.movies);
> ```

Your problem solved

Comment: final String titles[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles);
   int images[] = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.movies); add into onCreate() but not working

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are using `<array>` tag for saving the images of movies. i.e `<item>@drawable/movie1</item>` which actually saves a `integer` reference to that image.

```
<array name="movies">
</array>
```

You have to replace the `<array>` with `<integer-array>`.

```
<integer-array name="movies">
</integer-array>
```

Comment: sorry, not work

Answer (score 0):

Here is full solution:

```
public class CustomView extends Activity {


int images[] = {R.drawable.movie1, R.drawable.movie2, R.drawable.movie3, R.drawable.movie4, R.drawable.movie5};
List<String> movies;
ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.stackover);
    movies = new ArrayList<>();
    movies.add(0, "The Wizard of Oz (1939)");
    movies.add(1, "Citizen kane (1950)");
    movies.add(2, "A Hard Day's Night (1934)");
    movies.add(3, "A Funny (1959)");
    movies.add(4, "HELLO (1943)");

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.demoList);
    listView.setAdapter(new CustomList(StackOver.this, movies, images));
}

public class CustomList extends BaseAdapter {

    List<String> movie;
    int[] image;
    private Context context;

    public CustomList(Context context, List<String> movie, int[] image) {
        this.context = context;
        this.movie = movie;
        this.image = image;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return movie.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return movie.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_stack, null);
        }



        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView rating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
        TextView genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
        TextView year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.year);

        title.setText(movie.get(position));
        imageView.setImageResource(image[position]);
        rating.setText("4.5");
        genre.setText("DRAMA");
        year.setText("1990");

        return convertView;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thx, but i want to make data(images,movies) in xml source by array. and call at Actvity Class like   " String[] titles                            =getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles) "